# How to delete space of empty "section number"

Tags: spacing, sectioning, numbering

I have renewed the section number so that it doesn't display anything

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}
```

now the problem is that LaTeX is still reserving space for the section number although isn't displaying it, i.e., the section name is indented to the right and it doesn't cover up the space where the section number was supposed to be?

Comment: Using `\section*{Some Title}` is not an option? It omits the number, too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't do this.

Use `\section*` instead, or globally set `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` to remove section numbering.

Comment: `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` works as I am saved from adding * to all sections plus adding separate TOC entries